# Making a space for local variables in assembly

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, stack-pointer

So I do have to write an assembly program which would call extern C function. So I wrote simple `pow` function, I compiled my assembly program with this C code. Everything works. But as I saw from `-S` command from `gcc`, the compiler makes a space for local variables. I thought it would be like this:

```
int func(int number)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 0;
}
```

We have 3 local variables, so the compiler would `subl $12, %esp`. But it goes for `subl $16, %esp`. Even if I only left one number here, still it would decrement by `16`. Now I have my code:

`main.s`:

```
.section .data
.XD:
    msg: .ascii "%d\n"
    msg_len = . - msg

.text
.globl _pow
.globl main

main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl $5, %eax #like int a = 5;
    pushl %eax 
    call _pow #_pow(a);
    movl %eax, -8(%ebp)
    pushl -8(%ebp)
    pushl $.XD
    call printf #printf("%d\n", _pow(a));
    movl $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

`func.c`:

```
int _pow(int number)
{
    return number * number;
}
```

It works as expected, `./main` prints out `25`. But now, I don't `subl` anything from `%esp`. I mean I can add this line, but it doesn't change anything. I've searched through the internet and I found out that maybe my code works just by accident and generally I should decrement `%esp`. So my question here is: By what value should I decrement `%esp` in `main`? Should it be `12` or maybe `16`?

Comment: The use of `16` is very likely to keep the stack 16-byte aligned.

Comment: I guess you are right, but then should I make it always 16-byte aligned, or should I `subl` specific values?

Comment: The requirement is probably specified in the platform's application binary interface (ABI) documentation. Since it's a spec, you should follow it in order to be able to interact with other code.

Comment: this works by accident because of 2 reasons: 1) between `movl %eax, -8(%ebp)` and `pushl -8(%ebp)` nothing else does use your stack space (interrupts in 32b x86 protected mode are using their own stack space in kernel level). 2) the `pushl -8(%ebp)` will store the value exactly at the same position `[ebp-8]`, so you are overwriting that value with itself, thus not damaging anything (check in debugger if I simulated it in head correctly, verify `esp` and `ebp` addresses before/after `push`, and take a look in memory view on the values). Pushing something else would overwrite local var value.

Comment: And about aligning stack by `sub` and not `and` -> if the gcc has full control over function calls above, it knows the current stack alignment at particular depth of call, so it can produce an `sub esp,imm32` with constant like `16` reserving both space for local variables and aligning the stack to be again 16B aligned before future calls of further functions. So the `and esp,-16` is not the only possible way (although the `and` is more robust, as it works even if the state of stack was unknown upon entrance of such code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling a 32-bit C function you have to follow the [C calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). Unlike for 64-bit systems there is no explicit order for aligning the stack. I couldn't find a statement **when** such an alignment should take place. The stack might be "misaligned" after pushing the parameters.

If you want to align the stack you can simply AND -16 after you saved it (`movl %esp, %ebp`):

```
andl $-16, %esp                ; Align 16
```

Comment: This is exactly what `gcc` does, when compiling C code. Hmm, but then should I `subl` anything from esp, to make space for local variables?

Comment: First `subl` for local variables (if needed) and then `andl` for alignment. However, I'm quite sure that you don't need a 16-byte alignment for 32-bit C.

Comment: Okay, I know that I don't need it. But `gcc` does `subl` some values, but then it doesn't align it with `addl`iing it. I mean it does - with `leave` instruction. But the question here is - do I have to `subl` anything from `%esp`?

Comment: @Frynio: I say: No, you generally don't have to. Yes, if you use local variables. Use only 4-byte variables - for a 4-byte alignment. There is no "red zone" defined for 32-bit programs.

Comment: Okay, so if I have 3 local variables, ints, `a`, `b` and `c`. I initialize them. So then (before pushing and initializing them with values) I do have to `subl $12, %esp`, or is it just optional?

Comment: So if it isn't optional, then why can I run a program without it?

Comment: @Frynio: Lucky you.

Comment: gcc uses subtract not and.